# Embedding Microsoft Teams channel conversation into website

Tags: microsoft-teams

In one of my project, the Client wants to integrate Microsoft Teams Channel conversation/post on the website. Is there any way, can we integrate embed code of Microsoft Teams channel conversation/post like providing for Microsoft Stream videos/channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding Microsoft Teams UI directly into other applications is not supported. However you could read the channels messages using [Get Channel Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get-message?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) Graph APIs and render it.

**Note:** Before calling this API with application permissions, you must request access. For details, see [Protected APIs in Microsoft Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-protected-apis).